# Следует ли выделять запятыми "в случае чего-либо"?

Tags: пунктуация

Здесь не требуется запятая: *В случае благоприятного исхода(,) работа будет закончена сегодня*?

Answer (score 1):

Зададим вопрос: работа будет закончена сегодня (при каком условии?) - в случае благоприятного исхода. Я думаю, обособлять "в случае благоприятного исхода" необязательно, это обычное обстоятельство.

Однако в ПАС ***Лопатина*** есть такое замечание:"Обстоятельственные члены предложения, имеющие в своем составе производные предлоги и предложные сочетания (благодаря, вопреки, ввиду, в целях, в связи с, во избежание, вследствие, **по случаю**, по причине, при наличии, согласно с, в отличие от, в противоположность, наподобие, при условии, в силу, за отсутствием, несмотря на, невзирая на, спустя, независимо от и др.), **обособляются при** **подчеркивании их смысла**: Благодаря отцу, я и сестры знаем французский, немецкий и английский языки (Ч.); Сгнивший, серо-голубой от времени балкон, с которого, за отсутствием ступенек, надо было спрыгивать, тонул в крапиве, бузине, бересклете (Бун.)

У вас "в случае" тоже производный предлог, равный "при", так что запятую можно поставить, если вы подчёркиваете смысл первой фразы.